# Angular where to place $watch

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a promise object from which my page gets data something like:

```
promise.then(function (data) {
    $scope.myData = data;
});
```

and outside of the then callback I have watches on objects on the page.  If I am going to watch some piece of data that my promise provides, should I always place my #watches inside of the then callback of the promise?

Answer (score 0):

When you $watch an object, it's really just registering a subscription to changes of the existing object. It won't run until a change is registered, so having it inside the resolve of a promise isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought in principle you would only want to setup your $watch once after you have declared the variable receiving the data. Without seeing the code it's difficult to be certain but I would expect problems if I set a $watch each time a promise returned.

The callback function of the $watch is passed both the old and new value so you can inspect the values to determine watch action to take.

Answer (score 0):

You should retrieve your data from a service:

```
app.factory('myService', function($http) {
   var someData = [];
   return {
       getData: function() {
           var promise = $http({method:'GET', url:'/api/someurl' });
           promise.success(function(data) { 
               angular.copy(data, someData);
           });

           return promise;
       },
       data: someData
   }
```

});

And then assign the data to your scope inside your controller

```
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope, myService) {
    $scope.data = myService.data;
});
```

Consume the data within your HTML, or from inside your directive

```
<body ng-app="app">
     <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in data">{{ item }}</li>
     </ul>
     <my-directive model="data"></my-directive>
</body>
```

If you do go with a custom directive, it is recommended to setup your $watch inside your directive's link function:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() { 
     return { 
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
            scope.$watch('data', function(newVal) {
                 ...
            });
        }
     }
});
```

There is no reason for $watch handlers to be inside the callback of a promise. It should  remain separate so that there is a clean separation between how the data is retrieved from the service and how the data is consumed from the view.